# Using Neural Networks to predict stock values

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, neural-networks

How are neural networks usually used to predict market evolution?
My data consists of a set of pairs (time, value), taken at an interval of 15 minutes.

My ideas so far are:

I.Take 40 values (or another arbitrary number) as inputs and try to estimate the following 50 values(again, arbitrary). This has the problem that once the neural network is generated, I can only produce 50 estimations.

II.Take time as an input and the value as an output. This is more slower but can create more estimations.

I would love any answers or references to articles about the subject.

Comment: What do you mean by *once the neural network is generated, I can only produce 50 estimations*? Also, I am skeptical about the idea that *time* could be driving *stock prices* (unless *time* is a proxy for the cumulative effect of inflation or the like, but that should be totally negligible when you have data recorded as frequently as at 15 minutes intervals). Also, I suppose you are talking about *stock prices* (which are observable) rather than *stock values* (which are unobservable).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some memory based recurrent neural network. Google created a so-called Neural Turing Machine, that is able to predict long sequences of data:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5401v2.pdf

But I have a feeling that it's a bit hard to implement ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need read about Neural Network Autoregression.
Check it at Google search, you will find a lot of publications and libraries.

For example: http://forecasters.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/Thielbar_Dickey_IIF_Submission-2.pdf